# multiple virtual env usage for different directories inside single workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a project in which I use multiple python virtual environments. For each directory, I use one different virtual environment. Is it possible to configure this in order to not change environment manually each time I need to execute files in another dir?

Just to be more clear, if my workspace is like this:

```
dir1
   file1.py
   file2.py
dir2
   file3.py
   file4.py
```

I would like to link `dir1` with virtual env `venv1` and `dir2` with `venv2`. This way, whenever I run `file1.py` or `file2.py`, it would automatically use `venv1`, and if I run `file3.py` or `file4.py`, it should use `venv2`.

I'm checking this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_module) and my first thought is configuring it with a debugging launch file via the 'python' argument. The problem with this is that I should create multiple launch options and execute each python file in debug mode.

Is there any other way? Like using workspace setttings (json file) but for each subdirectory I have? Or maybe using the settings of the workspace with a custom variable that is changed based on the directory where I execute the python file?

Comment: what if you use a Multi Root Workspace and set a different python interpreter (virtual environment) in each workspace (`dir1` and `dir2`)

Comment: I just come to this solution some minutes ago. It's a little pain the need to import each directory into the workspace as independent workspace, but definitely it's an effective solution to my problem.

Comment: I don't think you have 100 directories and you don't have to do the imports each day

Comment: why do you have multiple virt envs for this workspace, what is different about them and why can't you merge them into one

Comment: I'm using envs that are for similar tasks, but the libraries have conflicting internal packages, so I can't install all in the same virtual env. For example they use different versions of tensorflow and numpy

Comment: I have answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72714616/9938317)