# How to dynamically switch python interpreter in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I have a project workspace with multiple microservices, how can I make VS Code switch between python interpreters to the nearest virtual environment folder?

For example:

- Workspace/folder1/src/main.py uses Workspace/folder1/.venv/
- Workspace/folder2/src/main.py uses Workspace/folder2/.venv/
- Workspace/folder3/src/main.py uses Workspace/.venv/
- Workspace/folder4/toolsfolder/tool1/main.py uses Workspace/folder4/toolsfolder/tool1/.venv/

```
Workspace/
├── folder1/
│   ├── .venv/
│   └── src/
│       └── main.py
├── folder2/
│   ├── .venv/
│   └── src/
│       └── main.py
├── folder3/
│   └── src/
│       └── main.py
├── folder4/
│   └── toolsfolder/
│       ├── tool1
│       │   ├── .venv/
│       │   └── main.py
│       ├── tool2
│       │   ├── .venv/
│       │   └── main.py
│       └── README.md
├── .venv/
├── Makefile
└── README.md
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible to do automatically. There are settings flags for automatically activating virtual environments, but I don't think it's triggered just by clicking into a directory in your workspace and I don't know if it sets the interpreter. You can always use the `Select interpreter` command to manually switch.

Comment: `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true` and `"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "~/venv/bin/python"` I think are the relevant settings, but I've never needed this functionality so I'm not certain.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automatically activate the correct environment and start debugging the current active editor you have to split the starting the debugger and attach the client (VSC) to the debugger.

Write a shell script that has as argument the current file path. The script will activate the correct Python environment and start a debugger on the given file path that waits for the client.

I have described this process and what to use as commands in [another Python Debug answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70488390/9938317)

The task to use is:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Script to activate specific environment and debug",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "activate-env-and-debug ${workspaceFolder} ${relativeFile}",
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ]
}
```

In the script to start the debugger use a command like:

```
python <path>/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy
  --listen 5678 --wait-for-client $1/$2
```

Because the environment is active `python` should execute the correct interpreter.

The version number of the `ms-python.python` extension will vary after updates, maybe you can extract the current (latest) by enumerating the extensions folder and search for the one with the largest version number (by parts) (they don't use 2 months digits)

Comment: Thank you for your input. I set a launch configuration using the `python` property to select the specific Python interpreter.
Do you know if it's possible to trigger multiple launch configurations to start multiple debuggers?I saw that we could use `dependsOn` with tasks, but I don't find a way to activate multiple launches at once.

Comment: @DanielDias You can setup [Multi-target debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_multitarget-debugging), but with the `python` launch property you have to create a launch config for every virt environment

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to use multiple environments in the same workspace.

I think it would be better to separate them in different workspaces in order to  avoid environmental chaos.

The chosen python interpreter is specific to the current workspace, instead of  an independent directory. If you like, you could manually select the interpreter (`ctlr+shift+P`) when using different folders.

Comment: It's a platform project, and it has multiple microservices APIs that were developed over time. While developing it, we run all APIs to run the platform locally. To run it is fine; we have a makefile that goes through all APIs, activates the python venv, and runs the API, but to debug the code, I need to run it with VSCode debug, and in this case, it will use the VSCode Python interpreter.

Comment: I imagine this same use case with a monorepo. You want the whole repo in one workspace, but you want separate venv for each service.